# How to custom the json send using postObject with RestKit?

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I am using restkit to post the create action to my rails application from mu ipad application. I Create the mapping for attributes :

```
- (void) initCustomerMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *customerSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"id"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"lastname" toAttribute:@"lastname"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"firstname" toAttribute:@"firstname"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"house_name" toAttribute:@"house_name"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"sci" toAttribute:@"sci"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"water_used" toAttribute:@"water_used"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"address_line_1" toAttribute:@"address_line_1"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"address_line_1" toAttribute:@"address_line_2"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"postal_code" toAttribute:@"postal_code"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"city" toAttribute:@"city"];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:customerSerializationMapping forClass:[Customer class]]; 
}
```

And i send the request :

```
    Customer* customer = [[Customer alloc] init]; 
    customer.lastname = lastname.text;
    customer.firstname = firstname.text;
    customer.house_name = house_name.text;
    customer.sci = sci.text;
    customer.water_used = water_used.text;
    customer.address_line_1 = address_line_1.text;
    customer.address_line_2 = address_line_2.text;
    customer.postal_code = postal_code.text;
    customer.city = city.text;

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:customer delegate:self];
```

But the json send looks like :

```
 {"water_used"=>"710", "house_name"=>"test", "address_line_1"=>"test", "city"=>"test", "sci"=>"546", "firstname"=>"test", "lastname"=>"test", "address_line_2"=>"test", "postal_code"=>"75896"}
```

And i want to get :

```
   { "customer" => 
       {"water_used"=>"710", "house_name"=>"test", "address_line_1"=>"test", "city"=>"test", "sci"=>"546", "firstname"=>"test", "lastname"=>"test", "address_line_2"=>"test", "postal_code"=>"75896"}
    }
```

How can i configure that? I tried to use **forKey** but i failed

**EDIT**

You can also use :

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider registerMapping:customerSerializationMapping withRootKeyPath:@"customer"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an other solution. In the string of toAttribute, i write it as an array :

```
- (void) initCustomerMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *customerSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"customer[id]"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"lastname" toAttribute:@"customer[lastname]"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"firstname" toAttribute:@"customer[firstname]"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"house_name" toAttribute:@"customer[house_name]"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"sci" toAttribute:@"customer[sci]"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"water_used" toAttribute:@"customer[water_used]"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"address_line_1" toAttribute:@"customer[address_line_1]"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"address_line_1" toAttribute:@"customer[address_line_2]"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"postal_code" toAttribute:@"customer[postal_code]"]; 
    [customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"city" toAttribute:@"customer[city]"];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:customerSerializationMapping forClass:[Customer class]]; 
}
```

It gives me my json :

```
  { "customer" => 
       {"water_used"=>"710", "house_name"=>"test", "address_line_1"=>"test", "city"=>"test", "sci"=>"546", "firstname"=>"test", "lastname"=>"test", "address_line_2"=>"test", "postal_code"=>"75896"}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should certainly add one more object, which contains Customer attribute.

For exemple :

```
#import "Customer.h"

@interface SOCustomer : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) Customer* customer;
@end
```

After this, you must change serialization. Maybe like this :

```
RKObjectMapping *customerSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]; 
[customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"id"]; 
[customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"lastname" toAttribute:@"lastname"]; 
[customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"firstname" toAttribute:@"firstname"]; 
[customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"house_name" toAttribute:@"house_name"]; 
[customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"sci" toAttribute:@"sci"]; 
[customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"water_used" toAttribute:@"water_used"]; 
[customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"address_line_1" toAttribute:@"address_line_1"]; 
[customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"address_line_1" toAttribute:@"address_line_2"]; 
[customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"postal_code" toAttribute:@"postal_code"]; 
[customerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"city" toAttribute:@"city"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:customerSerializationMapping forClass:[Customer class]];

// added
RKObjectMapping *vocustomerSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
[vocustomerSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"customer" toRelationship:@"customer" withMapping:customerSerializationMapping ];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:vocustomerSerializationMapping  forClass:[Customer class]];
```

I can not test this code, but I think it's the right way.
Just find how to serialize correctly.

Hope this can help you.